# Real-Time TCP session reconstruction in Java using jPcap

Tags: java, networking, tcp, jpcap

I am listening a specific network card and capturing TCP(just TCP) packets using jPcap library. However, I need to have whole TCP sessions, not individual packets.

In Wireshark, I can choose "follow tcp stream", so that I can get the whole conversation from beginning to end. I want to do exactly that in Java. How can I reconstruct these packets in real-time? I want to reconstruct TCP sessions while listening the network card and capturing new packets. How can I achieve this? Here is my code to capture packets:

```
jpcap.NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
            JpcapCaptor captor = JpcapCaptor.openDevice(devices[1], 65535, true, 1000);
            JpcapWriter writer = JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(captor, "myNetworkDump");
            captor.loopPacket(-1, new PacketPrinter(writer));
```

---

```
class PacketPrinter implements PacketReceiver {

    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Packet>> sessions;
    private BufferedWriter out;
    private JpcapWriter writer;

    Map<Long, TCPBodyData> bodies = new HashMap<Long, TCPBodyData>();

    public PacketPrinter(JpcapWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.sessions = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<Packet>>();
    }

    public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {
        System.out.println(packet);
        if (packet instanceof TCPPacket) {
            TCPPacket tcppacl = (TCPPacket) packet;
            byte[] body = addBodyData(tcppacl);
            // System.out.println(new String(body));
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about jPcap (and I remember reading somewhere - [here](http://jnetpcap.com/node/650) that you should rather use jNetPcap) but I would use a `HashMap<String,TCPPacket>` the tcp conversation according to store the conversation, the `String` key being for instance `String.join('.',remotehost_tcp_address,remote_host_tcp_port)`, then wait for a RST or FIN-FIN+ACK-ACK sequence to remove it.

Note that it might be a costly operation if your system experience a heavy network load, and you also might want to watch for timed out conversations.

Comment: There are at least three different projects called jPcap, of varying quality.

Answer (score 1):

The [pcap-reconst](http://code.google.com/p/pcap-reconst/) project provides a framework for reconstructing TCP stream from pcap files. You can use the method `public void reassemblePacket(TcpPacket tcpPacket)` of the class [`TcpReassembler`](http://code.google.com/p/pcap-reconst/source/browse/trunk/src/java/pcap/reconst/reconstructor/TcpReassembler.java?r=2) to do the job.

```
/*
* The main function of the class receives a tcp packet and reconstructs the stream
*/
public void reassemblePacket(TcpPacket tcpPacket) throws Exception {
    ....
}
/*
 *Get the TCP stream
 */
 public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return outputStream;
}

/*
 * Reconstructs the tcp session
 * @param sequence Sequence number of the tcp packet
 * @param length The size of the original packet data
 * @param data The captured data
 * @param data_length The length of the captured data
 * @param synflag
 * @param net_src The source ip address
 * @param net_dst The destination ip address
 * @param srcport The source port
 * @param dstport The destination port
 */
 private void reassembleTcp(long sequence, long ack_num, long length, byte[] data, 
                            int dataLength, boolean synflag,
                            TcpConnection tcpConnection) throws Exception {
      ....
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be what OP asking for.

Comment: OP said: "How can I reconstruct these packets in real-time? I want to reconstruct TCP sessions while listening the network card and capturing new packets." I answer to that. The code, he provided is just a trial.

Comment: Your answer is about reconstructing *packets.* He is asking about reconstructing *sessions.*

Comment: In the first sentence, I've made a mistake and interchanged packet and stream but now it's corrected. The rest of the answer is correct. The method reassemblePacket receives a tcp packet and reconstructs the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to group packets by source host, source port, destination host, destination port and consecutives sequence numbers. To know when a session begins you can check packets with SYN set to 1, at this moment you can capture the ISN (Initial Sequence Number) and all later packets with ISN+1..ISN+n will be in the same tcp stream. To know when a session ends you have to check for a FIN packet.
Wikipedia's link is not bad http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol but for better and deep reading I recommend you "TCP/IP Illustrated vol.1".

Comment: fin packets will definitely end conversations that' s right. But what about rst' s?

Comment: I think you can still use ACK sequence number from RST packet to associate it to  the right tcp stream but I'm not sure.